# Windows 10 on Dell XPS13 can pair bluetooth headphones, but cannot connect

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones

I am using a Dell XPS13 (Skylake edition) with Windows 10 and have issues using my brand new Sony MDR-1000X headphones with my computer. They pair just fine with my Android phone and even with another Windows 10 Desktop computer with bluetooth dongle. Also, I have had trouble connecting a Bluetooth JBL speaker and a BOSE QC35 headphone with this XPS laptop, so I am pretty sure the laptop (Windows or the drivers or the hardware) is the problem.

If I set my headphones to pairing mode, I can see them on my computer and pair them. However, it doesn't go any further then pairing. My headphones also don't agree on being connected, which is indeed the case.

If I go to playback devices (by right-clicking the volume icon) I can see the headphones and their status is disconnected, though enabled. If I right-click the headphones here, I can click 'connect'. However literally nothing happens when I click this. I have tried everything that is described in [Windows 10 computer paired w/ bluetooth speaker, but doesn't send music to speaker](https://superuser.com/questions/1024006/windows-10-computer-paired-w-bluetooth-speaker-but-doesnt-send-music-to-speak). That means I have:

- Tried updating the Bluetooth drivers
- Stopped and restarted the Bluetooth support service, and I have also set it to autostart
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers
- Turned off Bluetooth and turned it on again
- Tried disabling the Microsoft Bluetooth emulator (and the one with LE)

I also tried connecting via 'Connect' in the action center. It then also pairs and I can tell it to connect. In this case I get 'Couldn't connect' in yellow.

I cannot imagine it is not possible to pair a new bluetooth playback device to a relatively new computer these days.. So any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Some extra information on my drivers:
These are the Bluetooth drivers in Device Manager:
[Device Manager Bluetooth drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQRvq.png)
If I go to their properties, the drivers for the first one (Dell Wireless 1820A Bluetooth 4.1 LE) are of date 23/09/2015. The other three (MDR-1000X, Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator, Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator) are of date 21/06/2006. I cannot update any of them: according to Windows they are up to date.

Edit: added BOSE QC35 headphones as a tested device.

Comment: I'm very sure now that it is driver related. It is not a Microsoft problem though. The problem is with the hardware specific drivers, which in my case means that Dell needs to update their drivers. Unfortunately I haven't had the time yet to contact them about this.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm also having the same issues with Dell XPS15 :(

Comment: I've had my laptop shipped to Dell for repairs (for some other things). They replaced the WiFi/Bluetooth adapter but this didn't make a difference. They had not reinstalled Windows though, so when I got it back and it still wasn't working I just reinstalled Windows since I had already taken all my data off and that fixed the problem! No guarantee though that this will be everyone's fix but you could give it a try....