# Paired bluetooth speaker shows as disconnected in windows 10 sound control panel

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, speakers

I have an RSON bluetooth speaker paired with a Windows 10 laptop over Bluetooth.

However in Control Panel > Sound > Playback, the RSON speaker is listed twice as headset & headphones and in both cased `Disconnected`.

I've tried everything listed at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1024006/windows-10-computer-paired-w-bluetooth-speaker-but-doesnt-send-music-to-speak#_=_), but the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to Device Manager and disabled the two RSON devices there. Disconnected from Bluetooth, reconnected to Bluetooth, and the device is now listed properly under Control Panel > Sound > Playback, and works fine when selected.